# jQuery - load url value

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, url, submit

I'm looking at implementing this country selector http://baymard.com/labs/country-selector

One change I'm stuggling to make is: instead of just showing an alert pop-up once submitted, I'd like it so that when the forms value="[url]" to load that page when submitted.

Currently this is the script:

```
<script>
  (function($){
    $(function(){
      $('select').selectToAutocomplete();
      $('form').submit(function(){
        alert( $(this).serialize() );
        return false;
      });
    });
  })(jQuery);
</script>
```

I've tried a number of different solutions but I end up losing the typing fuctionality and reverting back to a standard drop down with the links working. Any ideas on how I could get both working?

Here's a snippet of the html:

```
<form>
<select style="padding:10px; width:200px;" name="Country" id="country-selector" autofocus autocorrect="off" autocomplete="off">
<option value="http://manchester.china-consulate.org/eng/" data-relevancy-booster="3.5" data-alternative-spellings="CN Zhongguo Zhonghua Peoples Republic 中国/中华">China</option>
</select>

<input style="padding:10px;" type="submit" value="Submit">
```

Comment: Elaborate on that please `forms value="[url"]`.

Comment: I believe he menas that there is an input form element named "value", which holds the url he needs to redirect after submission of the form.

Comment: Don't give us a link to the page, provide a minimal snippet that demonstrates the problem. Links break, making your question turn into nonsense; Examples will always be useful to others once your question has been answered. Plus, giving us a link assumes we'll chase down the needed information necessary to help you, but instead they tend to discourage people who would answer you, so help us help you.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the heads up - will be more specific when providing code snippets in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add location.href to redirect the page. since you didn't add html of your code, i've added a javascript to get the input field value with a name "value";

```
<script>
  (function($){
    $(function(){
      $('select').selectToAutocomplete();
      $('form').submit(function(){
        var url = document.getElementsByName("value")[0].value;
        window.location.href = url;
        return false;
      });
    });
  })(jQuery);
</script>
```